# Footnotes with automatic final period

Tags: footnotes, punctuation, automation

I'm tired to always add a period at the end of the `\footnote` command. Is there the possibility that LaTeX automatically does this at the end of every footnote?

Comment: Also see the subsequent discussion at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33626/5764

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could redefine the way `\@makefntext` works and add this in the definition. `\@makefntext` is the final macro that is executed in the standard document classes for constructing the footnote. In the below MWE, I've added `.` after `#1`, where `#1` is the argument supplied to `\footnote{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1.}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
\end{document}​
```

As per your request, this will be added to *every* footnote. And therefore, even if you have an entire (punctuated) paragraph as a footnote, the last sentence should be period-less.

Comment: But what happens if the user sometimes puts the final dot, and sometimes not?  It *is* possible to make a smart macro that checks for the final dot - just more complicated.  Hint: the model is xspace.sty :)

Comment: Then they'll get 2 periods and sometimes 1. Okay, seriously... The OP's request included the words "automatically does this at the end of every footnote." I guess it would be possible to check whether the argument ends in `.` by using an [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) `\IfEndWith` command. [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) reads a character that *follows*, not something contained *within*.

Comment: Exactly.  Actually the rule should be "add period unless the footnote ends with ., !, ?, ' or ''".  It is easy to implement with xstring, of course...

Comment: @Boris: Interesting idea. You could ask that as a follow-up question referring to this one, and see what kinds of answers come up.

Comment: You might also be able to query the spaceskip at the end of a footnote to test whether it ends in punctuation.

Comment: @doncherry: to say the truth I can code this myself  without asking :).

Comment: @Will-Robertson: Thanks, it is a good idea.  I thought about analyzing token by token, but this one is much more elegant.

Comment: @Will-Robertson: Ok, posted the solution.

Comment: @Boris: I figured you could, I was just thinking about keeping things findable, i.e. not answering to this question with something that wasn't really asked for; but I guess it's fine this way, too.

Answer (score 16):

The solution by Werner solves the the original poster's problem, but just for the fun of it let us solve a more general one.  Suppose the user *sometimes* puts the periods, and sometimes does not.  We want our macro to insert a period *only* if the footnote does not end with a period, a question mark or a bang.

The following solution is based on the idea by Will Robertson in the comments.  It needs `nonfrenchspacing` to work (it is possible to make a more general one, but this will suffice for now).  Basically we check the `\spacefactor` of the last letter in the footnote and add period if it is too small (3000 is the plain and latex default for the end of a sentence)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1%
  \ifnum\the\spacefactor<3000.\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.  More
text\footnote{This footnote ends by a full stop.}.  Even more
text\footnote{End with a bang!}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good solution but try `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`.

Comment: @yiannis-lazarides: well, `spanish.ldf` sets `\frenchspacing`, so this trick is not supposed to work.  In a production version I'd examine `\sfcode`s at the beginning of the footnote, and make them odd for sentence end and even otherwise (adding 1 would not change them much).  Then I could use `\ifodd` to check.