# Feeding arguments to xstring macros

Tags: conditionals, text-manipulation, xstring

In [Footnotes with automatic final period](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33254/footnotes-with-automatic-final-period), the comment was made to provide the possibility to add a period `.` to a footnote conditionally, based on whether the footnote already has a period or not. I immediately thought [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) would solve this conditioning using `\IfEndWith` and attempted the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1\IfEndWith{#1}{.}{}{.}}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
\end{document}
```

Here the footnote ends with the condition `\IfEndWith{#1}{.}{}{.}` to check whether `#1` (the argument to `\footnote`) ends with `.`. If true, it does nothing, else it prints a `.`. This works without a hitch when you use `\IfEndWith{xstring.}{.}{}{.}`, but not here. TeX complains about an `Undefined control sequence`.

A related problem dealing with file extensions - [How to make nonstopmode really not stop on a missing input file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33086/how-to-make-nonstopmode-really-not-stop-on-a-missing-input-file) - was solved (or didn't complain like the above problem, yet it had a similar set up in terms of `xstring`) using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\let\OldInputIfFileExists\InputIfFileExists
\renewcommand{\InputIfFileExists}[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\OldInputIfFileExists{#1}{#2}}%
    {\IfEndWith{#1}{.tex}{\typeout{INPUT #1}}{\typeout{INPUT #1.tex}}}%
  }
\begin{document}
This is dummy text.
\input{missing}% missing.tex is missing
\input{missing.tex}% missing.tex is missing
\end{document}
```

The idea in the above MWE (slightly modified from the original post) is to check whether a file to be `\input`ed exists or not, and write out some information to the `.log` file, appending the extension `.tex` as necessary. The selected output in the `.log` file after compiling the above should be

```
...
INPUT missing.tex
INPUT missing.tex
...
```

So, why does passing the argument `#1` to `\IfEndWith` cause a problem in the former MWE, but not the latter?

Now, I do know that the [`xstring` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) clearly states:

> [`xstring`] provides macros and tests operating on "strings of tokens"
>   ... A "string of tokens" is a list of tokens of any nature, except
>   that braces must be balanced and tokens catcode 6 and 14 (usualy `%`
>   and `#`) are not allowed. Apart from this, any token is allowed, in
>   any order in the list, whatever be the resulting code.

But why then does the second MWE compile without problem? I'm assuming a correction of my use would extend to all of the `xstring` macros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As unbonpetit suggests, one problem is that `\IfEndWith` performs an `\edef` on its argument. However, the argument to `\@makefntext` is *not* the footnote text, but rather

```
\rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces This is a footnote\@finalstrut\strutbox
```

so `\IfEndWith` will never succeed in finding a final dot. You have to do the check on the argument passed to `\@footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {#1}
  {#1\protect\IfEndWith{\detokenize{#1}}{.}{}{.}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.
\end{document}
```

However, this will fail if the footnote text ends with `!` or `?`.

The approach taken by AMS in **amsthm** is different and worthy of attention:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%%% taken from amsthm.sty
\def\@addpunct#1{%
  \relax\ifhmode
    \ifnum\spacefactor>\@m \else#1\fi
  \fi}
\def\nopunct{\spacefactor 1007 }
\def\frenchspacing{\sfcode`\.1006\sfcode`\?1005\sfcode`\!1004%
  \sfcode`\:1003\sfcode`\;1002\sfcode`\,1001 }
%%% end of borrowed code
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {#1}
  {#1\protect\@addpunct{.}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.
Here is some text\footnote{Is this a footnote?}.
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote without final period\nopunct}.
\end{document}
```

One can add `\nopunct` at the end of the footnote text in special cases when the final period is not desired (for instance, if the footnotes ends with `\dots`).

Comment: However, this solution does not work when the package `hyperref` is loaded.

Comment: @Matthew Which one?

Comment: None of them works

Comment: @Matthew Please ask a new question with all the details.

Answer (score 4):

In your first MWE, xstring complians because it tries to expand `#1` with an `\edef` and cannot because `#1` is not "`This is a footnote`":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \def\foo{#1}\show\foo}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote}.
\end{document}
```

As you see, #1 is "`\rule \z@ \footnotesep \ignorespaces This is a footnote\@finalstrut \strutbox`". Have a look at the `\@footnotetext` macro to see how it works.

For your second question, I am not sure that xstring is implied:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\OldInputIfFileExists\InputIfFileExists
\renewcommand{\InputIfFileExists}[2]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\OldInputIfFileExists{#1}{#2}}%
    {foobar}%
  }
\begin{document}
This is dummy text.
\input{missing}% missing.tex is missing
\input{missing.tex}% missing.tex is missing
\end{document}
```

The behaviour is still the same. I'm sorry, I cannot search a solution, I have to go to work!

Comment: With e-TeX, it's usually easier to use `\showtokens{#1}` to see the argument, rather than do an assignment.