# Footnote with automatic final period not working with "Ibid."

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, punctuation, automation, biblatex-chicago

I'm using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33269/209996) solution to automatically add a period at the end of every footnote; the code should insert a period only if the footnote does not already end with a period, a question mark or a bang.

However, one too much period is added when I use `citestyle=authoryear-ibid` in `biblatex` (with `authoryear-ibid` "immediately repeated citations are replaced by the abbreviation ‘"Ibid.’").

This is what i get:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
    style=chicago-authordate,
    citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
    ibidpage=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

% This macro inserts a period only if the footnote does not end with a period, a question mark or a bang
\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1%
  \ifnum\the\spacefactor<3000.\fi}
\makeatother
  
\begin{document}

This works \footcite{Gomme1956} 
Here one too many period is added \footcite{Gomme1956}

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid that one too much period is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` changes the space factors of certain punctuation commands for a finer control over punctuation and to avoid punctuation clashes. In this case the period produced by `biblatex` has space factor 1006 (`\blx@sf@period`), so we need to check against that as well

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
  style=chicago-authordate,
  citestyle=authoryear-ibid,
  ibidpage=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1%
  \ifnum\the\spacefactor<3000
    \ifnum\the\spacefactor=\blx@sf@period
    \else
    .%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This works \footcite{sigfridsson}
Here one too many period is added \footcite{sigfridsson}
Lorem\footnote{Blob}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998.//2 Ibid.//3 Blob.]

Note that you don't need the extra code at all if the only footnotes you are ever using are produced by `\footcite`: `biblatex` automatically adds the period.

Comment: Perfect! I need that extra code because I also use `\footnote`.